# Logitech Lua to input two keys in a cycle

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

So I need a logitech lua which does the following

When pressed it should input 1 but when double pressed/pressed again, it should input 2.

Is it doable?

Thank you

I tried creating a variable with no value and when pressed once i made it change its value to x and input 1 keystroke and so when i press the button again and if the value of variable is x then it needs to input 2 keystroke .

Idk the codes , kept saying syntax error

Comment: What should the script input on double click?  `12` or `2`?

Comment: On double click, 2

Comment: What key/button should be monitored for press/double press?  What means `in a cycle`?

Comment: @ESkri Okay SO When I press the button for the first time, I want it to input "1" and when I press the button again, I want it to input "2" and again when i press the button again, i want it to input "1"..... so on

Answer (score 0):

A solution: change `index` to the next position of the cycle on each button press (here mouse button 6 is used)

```
local index = 1
local the_loop = {"1", "2"}

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == 'PROFILE_ACTIVATED' then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == 'MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED' and arg == 4 then
      index = 1
   elseif event == 'MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED' and arg == 6 then
      local the_key = the_loop[index]
      PressKey(the_key)
      Sleep(50)
      ReleaseKey(the_key)
      index = index % #the_loop + 1
   end
end
```

Comment: YESSSSS THANK YOU SO MUCH <3

Comment: Hey , One more feature request,
I want it to reset the loop when i press mouse button 4, is that possible?
By reset the loop i mean, I want the input to be strictly "1" when i press mouse button 6 after i press mouse button 4